# Custom button can't be shown in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-custom-view

When get in to the fragmentA at the first times, the button show as normal.

Then,I get fragmentB to replace fragmentA.

Then,I get fragmentA to replace fragmentB again and the button disappear in fragmentA.

What's the problem i met?

My custom button code : https://gist.github.com/zhongbaitu/26ad920cfb4273b3206c

My XML:
```

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="cn.zmn.nizaoma.FragmentNizaoma">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <cn.zmn.widget.RaisedButton
                android:id="@+id/question_one_but"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="问题1"/>

            <cn.zmn.widget.RaisedButton
                android:id="@+id/question_two_but"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="问题2"/>


        </LinearLayout>



        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/nizaoma_refesh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_nizaoma"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>




        </LinearLayout>






</FrameLayout>
```

```

thanks.

Comment: give us your onclicklisteners

Comment: the put the code here: https://gist.github.com/zhongbaitu/4ec00dbaa2a8d1360bdb

Comment: that code dont show the problem you describe above. only need the code about your custom buttons, i guess thats your problem...

Comment: the code of the custom button is here:https://gist.github.com/zhongbaitu/26ad920cfb4273b3206c any methor i miss to override? or something i should not to do that?

Comment: i had found the problem. i use "this.setBackgroundResource(0)" to take the button's background away and it made the button can't show normal. But i still have no idea to take the buttton's background away.Anyway, thanks for you help.